# How to extend expired date in Google OAuth2 library?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm using [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/) to create google calendar applications. This app's target is only developed for me. Actually I could succeed to get OAuth2 token via library, but its expiry_date is too short for me. Just now I get a new token which expiry date is 1447214080052, it only works 1 hour!

Unfortunately I couldn't find any expiry settings in this document. Are there any good ways to extend expiry date?

Comment: I might an find answer by myself. [Google's document](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync) shows refresh_token. And my token file contains not only expiry_date but also refresh_token. So if it has refresh_token, I don't need to care expiry date.

Comment: access tokens expire after an hour and you will need to use the refresh token to get another one.   If I was you I would look into a service account instead if its your data there is no reason to use Oauth2.

Comment: Great! I've never known about service account. I will set up my service account because my service is a server-side application.

Comment: Service accounts only work if you are accessing your own data.  If it is a calendar owned by another user then you cant use a service account you need to use Oauth2.